# Any Open Data Sets for the (Football) World Cup (in Brazil 2014)?

Tags: data-request, brazil, sports

Are there any public data sets for the World Cup in Brazil 2014?

Didn't find anything for download on the official FIFA site (besides a single-page PDF booklet for the match schedule).

Ideally the data set includes groups, teams, players, squads, matches, stadiums and so on
and is in an **open plain text format** such as CSV (comma-separated values), JSON (javascript objects), SQL (structured query language), etc.

Any insight appreciated.

Disclosure: I'm the project lead of the football.db project collecting open public domain football data e.g.

- [`openfootball/world-cup`](https://github.com/openfootball/world-cup)-  World Cup Datasets (1930-2022)

Comment: How does the FIFA license results, schedule etc?

Comment: Good question. Best to ask FIFA. I do not know.   Note that team names, cities names, player names, matche results etc. are facts (no copyright, no license needed). Cheers.

Comment: see this answer: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15389/1511

Answer (score 11):

**Edit**: A new initiative on the web [open_data_world_cup](http://slideshow-s9.github.io/open_data_world_cup.html)

**Edit 2**: Gerald also started collecting a list of other football projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/footballdata).

**Edit 3**: [Here](http://www.engagedata.eu/dataset/87642/world-cup-2014-player-ages/) is a list of the football players ages in a spreadsheet format.

You can create data by putting the information from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup) page into a more structured format.

There are plenty of tools available that make scraping easier. A starting point might be [ScraperWiki](https://scraperwiki.com/), but it depends a bit on your interest and skills.

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AheygzpA1RyrdDN0SmtCOWo3TWRfcXU4RjFJMmdxc3c&usp=sharing) a quick proof-of-concept with GoogleDocs' `ImportHTML` function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Great. How would you import match data (if not in a table or list), for example?

Comment: @GeraldBauer see the new link.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Fantastic project ;-) || Disclosure: I'm the project lead of the [open football project](https://github.com/openfootball). || Just wondering if there's anything else out there (for the world's biggest sport event).

Comment: haha, ok the circle is closed.

Answer (score 8):

I found one more free, open database you can use. http://openfootball.github.io/

**What’s football.db?**

A free open public domain football (soccer) database & schema for use in any (programming) language (e.g. uses plain text fixtures/data sets). Example:

```
### Teams

barcelona, Barcelona|FC Barcelona|Fútbol Club Barcelona, BAR, city:barcelona
madrid,    Real Madrid|Real Madrid CF,                   RMD, city:madrid
malaga,    Málaga|FC Málaga|Málaga CF|CF Málaga,         MAG, city:malaga
...
### Matches

2013-03-12 20:45  Schalke 04      2-3  Galatasaray
2013-03-12 20:45  Barcelona       4-0  Milan

2013-03-13 20:45  Málaga          2-0  Porto
2013-03-13 20:45  Bayern München  0-2  Arsenal
```

**License**

The football.db schema, data and scripts are dedicated to the public domain. Use it as you please with no restrictions whatsoever.

Try the football.db web admin app running on Heroku [footballdb.herokuapp.com](http://footballdb.herokuapp.com).

Answer (score 5):

You can find [here an excel file](http://www.excely.com/football/2014-fifa-world-cup-schedule.shtml#.UyV97_l_uSo) with the schedule of the tournament and the groups. Inside the folder, you will find a license txt file containing the following:

> LICENSE. The Software may be freely distributed.
>
> The Software is licensed to you. So, you may not:
>
> - rent, lease, grant a security interest in, or otherwise transfer rights to the Software;
> - modify or remove any proprietary notices or labels on the Software;
> - disassemble the Software;
> - change the executable code of the Software;
> - sell this Software both standalone and part of a purchasable collection of software without author's explicit permission.

Answer (score 5):

Mashape has an API listed for the World Cup 2014 which would return in Json some of the info you're looking for - https://www.mashape.com/leolima77/copa-do-mundo-2014-world-cup-brazil#!documentation

It is listed in Portugese so you might need to translate it to English.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a database of 736 players by scraping and refining.
The database (in French) is available here:
http://mondial-de-football.com/WorldCupData

It contains many data fields: age, number of selections, clubs, championship, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just added this API to mashape, it's not realtime and the scores will take awhile to be updated but it gives you all the teams and matchups.

https://www.mashape.com/montanaflynn/fifa-world-cup/

Comment: Is it fully updated now?