# Results data for Basketball World Cup

Tags: api, sports

This year will be the Basketball World Cup in Spain ([here the official web page](http://fiba.com/spain2014)), and I'm thinking in doing an app to keep track of all the teams and results.

Anyone kowns, if there is (or will be) any API that will provide those data?

Answer (score 1):

There is a question about a soccer API which has answers with many sports APIs - [LINK](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1007/1511).

Also, check out my [answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/2061/1511) there about the [ESPN Developer Center](http://developer.espn.com/) API, which should include the FIBA World Cup.

[**Note: The ESPN Developer APIs have been retired.**](http://developer.espn.com/blog/read/publicretirement)

Comment: Providing the relevant information in your answer would be so much more useful than just posting links. Especially the first link, that page only contain 1 answer which *might* be relevant to this question.