# Dataset of football (soccer) penalties

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm looking for a soccer penalty dataset containing as many following fields as possible:

- name of the player who shot the penalty
- name of the goalkeeper
- penalty outcome (success/fail)
- ball position, i.e. where player placed the ball (center, bottom left, )
- teams of the player and goalkeeper
- time of the penalty during the game
- player's position (attackers/midfield/defenders)
- datetime of the game
- competition name

Comment: i have this data and regularly produce graphics and stats connected to penalties at @stats4foooty if you are on Twitter. i have about 6,000 penalties from 22 leagues / cups.

Comment: Possibly related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/are-there-any-open-datasets-for-soccer-statistics/1009#1009

Answer (score 3):

I think FIFA used to keep this level of details on its archived statistics page. But now when you go to the url (http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/) you get a blank page! I found this reference from The Guardian that aggregated the statistics per team going back to 1930 thru 2006 and made available to download as a spreadsheet. It does not have individual player stats:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgdO92JOXxAOdGtRLThiUUhYSnhackhXVm9qbm5aQ0E#gid=0

If somebody can find copies of the archive, Brenna Curley, Iowa State University, wrote a paper (April 2012) for analyzing the dataset using R.

http://www.public.iastate.edu/~curleyb/Stat585_Project_FinalPDF.pdf