# Any Open Data Sets for the (Football) Women's World Cup (in Canada 2015)?

Tags: data-request, sports, canada

Are there any open public datasets for the Women's World Cup in Canada 2015?

Didn't find anything for download on the official FIFA site (besides a single-page PDF booklet for the match schedule that, of course, states: Copyright © 1994 - 2015 FIFA. All Rights Reserved.).

Ideally the dataset includes groups, teams, players, squads, matches, stadiums and so on and is in an open plain text format such as CSV (comma-separated values), JSON (javascript objects), SQL (structured query language), etc.

Any insight appreciated.

Disclosure: I'm the project lead of the football.db project collecting open public domain football data e.g. [openfootball/women-world-cup](https://github.com/openfootball/world-cup-women) - Women's World Cup Datasets (note: just a start incl. teams and match schedule - not complete in any way)

Comment: see this answer, in particular https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15389/1511