# Dataset of soccer betting odds and game results

Tags: data-request, sports, football

There is already a question about [soccer statistics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1007/930), which summarises many data sources for team listings, game results, and many more fields for national and international teams.

What I am now looking for is a dataset (no API needed, a historical/static file is sufficient) that contains **betting odds** (e.g. `0: 1.7, 1: 3.6, 2: 6.0`) before a football game **and** the **game's result** (e.g. `3:1`).

Purpose: I want to write a small function that emits "realistic" game results when handed the odds, so I would like some historic data for estimating the results' probability distribution.

Comment: Data from http://www.football-data.co.uk/ on https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be exactly what you need:

[oddsportal historical odds](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2014-2015/results/)

1. It gives you the odds and result for each game for multiple leagues
2. ... multiple years
3. ... and odds from multiple betting agencies.

This is a very neat data source.

You can easily scrape the data with `beautifulsoup` (and you might have to work with a webdriver like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control the page loading).

Comment: Wow, extremely extensive coverage - and I just checked their `soccer` section. Unfortunately, it is not strictly open data. But yeah, with beautifulsoup, some carefully selected queries (fortunately, they display a [many games per page](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/euro-2012/results/)) and I should have all I need.

Comment: There is only main problem - gathering/scrapy content from this site is prohibited by OddsPortal.

Comment: You can find a lot of soccer datasets and already prepared crawlers also at https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer

Answer (score 0):

Oddsportal offers unique data. Although, it's pretty unfriendly to scrape. I've been struggling to find a solution and having sorted it out after a long while wrapped the solution as an R package. I also plan to store the scraped data within the package.
https://github.com/ikashnitsky/oddor