# World Cup Winners

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for a data set that includes World Cup winners, the host country, runners up, etc. I have the winners currently, but would like to see more information. Scores and such for each would also be a bonus!

Comment: see this answer: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15389/1511

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dataset hosted here: https://www.datazar.com/file/f89abbe09-f107-4ea6-855e-86a9ea9e598f that includes winners, runners up, host country and additional notes for every year the World Cup was played.

In a separate dataset here: https://www.datazar.com/file/fdd9b39bb-1a23-4df2-8a3e-d0dba6a3c9fd there is information about scores, attendance and other additional information about each year. I hope this is helpful :)

Full Disclosure: I work at Datazar (A collaborative open data Library) where this project is hosted