# Any open data sets for the (Football) World Cup in Russia 2018? Any open data for the World's Biggest (Sport) Event?

Tags: data-request, sports, football, russia

Are there any public data sets for the World Cup in Russia 2018?

Didn't find anything for download on the official FIFA site (besides a single-page PDF booklet for the match schedule).

Ideally the data set includes groups, teams, players, squads, matches, stadiums and so on and is in an **open plain text format** such as CSV (comma-separated values), JSON (javascript objects), SQL (structured query language), etc.

Any insight appreciated.

Disclosure: I'm the project lead of the football.db project collecting open public domain football data e.g.

- [openfootball/world-cup](https://github.com/openfootball/world-cup) - World Cup Datasets (1930-2022)

so no need to highlight this [little humble dataset about Russia 2018](https://github.com/openfootball/world-cup/blob/master/2018--russia/cup.txt) ;-) (that incl. the teams, groups and match schedule) but is missing a lot (e.g. players, trainers, stadiums, etc. and once the events starts it's missing goal getters, goals, penalties, yellow cards, red cards, and on and on).

Again it's the world's biggest (sport) event - 1 000 000 000+ people watching live and there must be some more open data out there in this world. Help us find some datasets. Any insight appreciated.

Kickoff! Matchday 7! Any updates? Any open datasets?

Comment: good question. in a couple weeks 538 will come out with their WC predictions --> https://data.fivethirtyeight.com/ (2014 data here https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/world-cup-predictions)

Comment: Provisional squads are required to be submitted by 14 May, and final squads by 4 June: http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=2018/m=2/news=organising-committee-for-fifa-competitions-updates-on-the-fifa-world-cuptm-and-w.html

Comment: And it seems you already have all other data here: https://github.com/openfootball/world-cup/blob/master/2018--russia/cup.txt. You could also post answers to your previous questions.

Comment: > And it seems you already have all other data here.


A: No, not really. I try to add what I can. That dataset just incl. the teams and match schedule. It's missing all players, all stadiums, all trainers, and on and on. And once the world cup starts it's missing all scores, goals, yellow cards, red cards, and on and on.

Comment: >  You could also post answers to your previous questions.   Q: What previous questions? The question is to find open datasets for the world's largest (sport) event. My humble little dataset can't be the only one in the universe with more than 1 000 000 000+ people watching live. Again the question is where's the open data for World Cup in Russia 2018?

Comment: fifa will surely be releasing this, as transparent and ethical as they are...

Comment: see this answer: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15389/1511

Answer (score 2):

<s>No data yet, but this repo will store</s> game results and some other info

https://github.com/lsv/fifa-worldcup-2018

> To use the data in your app, you can use this link
>
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lsv/fifa-worldcup-2018/master/data.json
>
> Which will be updated

and also has some structured data about stadiums

```
{
  "id":
  "name": "Luzhniki Stadium",
  "city": "Moscow",
  "lat": 55.715765,
  "lng": 37.5515217,
  "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Luzhniki_Stadium%2C_Moscow.jpg"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Guides / collections for open football data include:

- [Guide to Football/Soccer data and APIs](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/guide-to-football-and-soccer-data-and-apis/) by Joe Kampschmidt; no update yet for the world cup 2018 in russia :-(
- [Football Data -Awesome Datasets @ DataHub.io](https://datahub.io/awesome/football) - No update yet for the world cup 2018 in russia :-(

Any others?

**(Update June/21st)**

My humble self has started a (static / pre-built) JSON HTTP API (micro) web service, see https://github.com/openfootball/world-cup.json.

Two other new (and old) JSON HTTP APIs include:

- https://github.com/lsv/fifa-worldcup-2018 (Hand-edited)
- https://github.com/estiens/world_cup_json (Auto-scraped from the FIFA World Cup Website almost in "real time")

Any others?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [our World Cup 2018 dataset](http://bigdata.duzce.edu.tr/#datasets) which contains **more than 38 million tweets** from almost **8 million unique Twitter users**. The dataset was constructed during the World Cup 2018. Since we have stored the data in a `MongoDB` instance, the exported data is available as a `MongoDB` dump. You can easily import the exported data into a `MongoDB` instance. In order to download the dataset, please follow the instructions available in the provided link above.

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle hosts a dataset that has the participating teams and their previous results against the teams in the group.

https://www.kaggle.com/ahmedelnaggar/fifa-worldcup-2018-dataset/data

> The dataset contains all the participating teams, the match schedule with orders of the matches, the previous matches between all teams with records of wins/losses/draws, the previous goals between all teams, the previous titles, semifinals, finals of all participating teams.

**(Update June/21st)** Note: No updates since the start of / kick off the World Cup e.g. missing match results, goals, and so on.

Comment: Great catch. Not to be picky. Looks a little too simplistic. Match info includes no date, no city, no stadium. Not sure how you will add the goals, penalties, etc..  Thanks for sharing / highlighting. It's a start.