# Looking for football (soccer) player data with salaries, heights, weights info

Tags: data-request, sports, football

I'm looking for dataset for all top world players or european players or though players of UEFA Champions League. So I'm intresting in multinational data (no for just one national ligue). I need table that in all cases contain: salaries, heights, weights.

Comment: See for example the FIFA Kaggle answer: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1007/1511

Comment: @philshem Do you mean the FIFA 18 Complete Player Dataset? It contains the wage info, hasn't heights, weights

Comment: what does ' or though players' mean?